# Fixed the width of select2

Tags: css, jquery-select2

I am using [`select2`](https://select2.github.io/examples.html) for selecting a candidate skill. 
I don't want to change my select box width, **I want Fixed width for my slelet2**

[image: Here is the Image]

What have I Tried So far?

```
//HTML
<select class="skill_select_id" name="skill_select_id">
    <?php foreach ( $skills as $skill ) { ?>
        <option value="<?= $skill['id'] ?>" ><?= $skill['name'] ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

First I use `resolve`

```
//Script 
$('.skill_select_id').select2({tags:true, width: 'resolve'});
```

I have also tried `element`, `100%` option in `width`

```
//Another Try
$('.skill_select_id').select2({tags:true, width: 'element'});
```

But it didn't help me to set a Fixed width of select2.

I don't want to add `inline CSS` to solve this problem because if I use the plugin then it must have some solution for this type of problems.

Comment: Can you share your code on jsfiddle.com or jsbin.com ?

Comment: @CodeWalker ok let me try because never created fiddle before.

Answer (score 6):

To fix my dropdown width, setting it to 'element' on select2 initialization worked fine for me:

```
$("#dropDown").select2({ width: 'element' });
```